# Limit bandwidth available to VMWare VM in VMWare Fusion

Tags: vmware-fusion, bandwidth

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth VMWare Fusion makes available to a particular VM?  I need to do some tests of behavior with limited bandwidth, and I figured limiting the VM image would be the easiest thing to do.  However, I'm not seeing any option for setting the speed in the VM's settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may install some 'bandwidth shaping' software on the VM (e.g. **[NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/)** on a Windows guest OS)

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to avoid that.  It seems like limiting the VM's adapter would be easier to do, and is a feature I'd expect a VM app to have.

Comment: Ended up settling for this.  I'd had problems with limiter software before but hadn't tried NetLimiter.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Teams in VMware](http://pubs.vmware.com/ws65_ace25/ws_user/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ws_user&file=ws_team.html).

However, I think you'll need one of the more expensive products like VMware Workstation to have this functionality available.

Comment: sadly I just have Fusion.